# django how to get model field as object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to get model's field as object
For example:
I have this model

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    email = models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

now I want to use the field as object
I want to be able to do this

```
def update_a_field(field):
    model_field = field
    query_set = User.objects.values(field.__name__).filter(field__isnull=False)
```

then I can call my function like this

```
name = User._meta.get_field("name")
update_a_field(name)
email = User._meta.get_field("email") 
update_a_field(email)
```

Comment: Why not just using `User.objects.values('name')` or `User.objects.values('email')`?

Comment: I need to set the field dynamically

Comment: Okay, I didn't see the `field` in `filter()` method. Then @Enthusiast Martin's answer should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def update_a_field(field):
    model_field = field

    filter_data = { "{}__isnull".format(field.__name__) : False}

    query_set = User.objects.values(field.__name__).filter(**filter_data)
```